# how to mirror a disk in windows server 2016 core

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, windows-server-core

I have a server with 2 identical hard drives. I installed windows server 2016 core on the 1 rt hard drive and now I would like to mirror (raid 1) the content of this hard drive on the hard Drive 2. How to do this from the command line ?

Comment: Diskpart.......

Comment: i know but how to do this with diskpart, just doing "add disk" and it's enaugh ?

Comment: We don't provide step by step instructions. There is an abundance of information available on the diskpart utility. You'll need to do your own research on how to use it to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done from administrative tools --> disk management, but if you want it from command prompt, you can use diskpart.

1st step is to convert the disks to dynamic:

```
select disk 1
convert dynamic
select disk 2
convert dynamic
```

Then, you must select the required to be mirrored volume(s) and assign the second disk:

```
select disk 1
select volume 1* 
add disk=2
```

*Make sure the volume you select is the desired one.

Other helpful commands:

```
list disk
list partition
```

Comment: Also, you can go with Storage Spaces instead of Dynamic disk mirroring. Storage Spaces Mirroring shows better performance, but requires more CPU resources.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly an option but I'd rather do further testing at this point until deciding to widely use this system.